# Beaglebone Local jQuery Files not Loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js

I'm working on a wireless robotics project utilizing node.js and jquery to create a webpage "controller".

Currently, my code is as below, however its functionality is limited to working with an internet connection due to the downloading of the scripts through the internet addresses. My goal is to allow this to function without internet connectivity

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">


    <!-- jQuery and jQuery Mobile -->
    <link rel="stylesheet"       href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

In order to try to save these files to the beaglebone locally, I created 3 files: Source1.css Source2.js and Source3.js which are copied and pasted into their respective files from the HTML links in the code above and stored in the same directory as the html and javascript files used for the server.

I have edited the code to appear as below

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">


<!-- jQuery and jQuery Mobile -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Source1.css" />
<script src="Source2.js"></script>
<script src="Source3.js"></script>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

However when I attempt to start the server using the node command, only the HTML appears to load in the webpage. I have attempted changing the charset and including the entire path to the jquery source files with no success. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is the HTML page in the same directory as the Source files?

Comment: What does your browser console say? No errors?

Comment: You should also add type="text/javascript" to your script tags just in case...

Comment: Yes my HTML page is in the same directory as the Source files. My browser console says 
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < 
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
I have seen other posts say this might have something to do with a charset? Happy to provide more details if necessary. This is my first post

Answer (score 0):

Disconnect from the Internet. Press Ctrl+Shift+I in the Chrome browser to load developer tools, change to the "Network" tab then press F5 to refresh the page. You will see the resources your page loaded (and some it attempted to load). Sort these results by the Initiator column. You will likely find Socket.IO initiated dependencies that failed to load.